# UITABLEVIEW call insert method when tapped

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I already have my insert method as well as editing. But what I wanted to know is how to recognise a touch event when tapping only the tablview to insert? This is similar to the Reminders app where you could touch anywhere within the UITableView to insert a new record.

```
UITableView *tableView = mytableview;
CGPoint tableLocation = [touch locationInView:tableView];

// this one recognises when I edit a record on a UITableview
if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    return NO;
}

if([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    return NO;
}

if([touch.view.superview.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    return NO;
}

// this one recognises if I tap on a UITableView
if ([tableView hitTest:tableLocation withEvent:Nil]) {


       //differentiate scrolling from tapping to invoke add method

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: maybe a UITapGestureRecognizer on the UITableView?

Comment: Thanks I already done that awhile ago, I'm just asking for an alternative solution if there is any out there.

Comment: right, maybe then loop thru visibleCells + detect which cell above or below to insert-into using rectForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: Thanks again that was my first solution. Please see my edited question. I put the code maybe you can help me.   What I wanted to know now is how could I distinguish scrolling from tap?

Comment: I think tap is cancelable, you can have your delegate run "insert" code with a delay, and cancel that "insert" if "tap" was cancelled eventually.

Comment: Oh geez forgot, I finally got it and eventually became more familiar with gesture recognizers. I'll post the answer.

Comment: Thats great! Have fun.

Comment: Thanks man you too until next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
  //check if your gesture is only TAP so you could scroll the uitableview

  if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {

    //making sure when you tap, you only tap within the uitableview

    UITableView *lemak_table = datetable;
    CGPoint tapaw_Kopi = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:lemak_table];

    if ([lemak_table hitTest:tapaw_Kopi withEvent:Nil]) {
        //Check if table is in editmode so you could tap buttons like "delete"
        if (![lemak_table isEditing]) {
            //INSERT METHOD HERE and NOWHERE ELSE FOR THAT MATTER.
        }

    }

  }
   return YES;
}


 // I also added this method so you could edit exisiting records per row/cell thus differentiating TAP to Add from TAP to edit. 

 -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:  (UITouch *)touch
  {

     if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        return NO;
     }

     if([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        return NO;
     }

     if([touch.view.superview.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        return NO;
     } 

   return YES; 
  }
```